# Página de erro 404 no IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, página-de-erro, iis

Boa tarde, eu desenvolvi um sistema e tenho uma lógica que não permite que perfis que não tem autorização acessem partes do sistema que não é permitido para ele. O que acontece é que, quando se tenta acessar uma área que não é permitida, o IIS dá uma página de erro 404(Not Found) em resposta a tentativa frustrada. O que eu queria saber é: Tem como eu colocar uma página de erro personalizada no IIS, pra que quando aconteça essa situação, mostre a minha página de erro personalizada ? Pois fico com medo em relação a segurança da minha aplicação.
Se alguém puder ajudar, ficaria grato !

Comment: Está usando MVC?

Comment: Exatamente, MVC mesmo.

Comment: Na minha aplicação eu customizei uma classe para fazer esse tipo de redirecionamento. Criei uma classe herdando a classe DefaultControllerFactory, depois sobrescrevi esse método: GetControllerInstance

Comment: É porque o meu problema é que, eu até tenho uma biblioteca que quando se tenta acessar uma página que não existe ele, redireciona pra uma página customizada. Ai tem um detalhe: Sem publicar no IIS, rodando pelo VS mesmo, quando eu tento acessar uma área não permitida por um perfil que não tem acesso, ele redireciona pra página de login de novo, ou seja, dá logout. Mas no IIS não, ele dá a página de 404. E eu não queria isso, queria uma página igual a que eu fiz, mas no IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem.

No seu arquivo `Web.config`, adicione o seguinte:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/SeuControllerDe404" />
    </customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Controller:

```
public class SeuControllerDe404 : Controller 
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div>Oops! Este endereço não existe.</div>
```

Comment: Teria como colocar um exemplo de como criar ? Digo: o Controller e a View ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Veja agora.

Comment: Agooora entendi ! Valeeu Cigano !

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tudo bem?

Sei que esta pergunta já foi respondida mas tem muito mais sobre isso já que, desse modo, você não vai conseguir retornar o erro 404 de maneira satisfatória.

O jeito mais seguro de fazer seria usando `<httpErrors>` dentro do `<system.webServer>`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/erro404.html" responseMode="File"/>
<httpErrors>
```

Desse modo você vai retornar tanto o HTTP status 404 quanto conserver a url original da página.

Você pode ver essa solução mais explicada neste artigo: http://davidsonsousa.net/pt/post/criando-paginas-de-erro-404-personalizadas-no-aspnet-mvc

Comment: Cara, parabéns. Seu post e sua resposta são excelentes ! Eu estou usando um pacote do nuget pra fazer esse redirecionamento. Mas dessa forma ai ta ótima ! E valeeu !